# Group array values by string in key?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Ok given this data structure:

```
array(
         'name one' => 'fred',
         'desc one' => 'lorem ipsum'
         'name two' => 'charles',
         'desc two' => 'lorem ipsum'
);
```

in php how do i go about matching the number value assigned to the key ONE or TWO and return this:

```
array(
           'one' => array('name' => 'fred', 'desc' => 'lorem ipsum'),
           'two' => array('name' => 'charles' , 'desc => 'lorem ipsum')
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: how does this not have " a clear problem statement"  as is required I have X I want Y??? is that not clear enough @Rizier123

Comment: It is clear, but it doesn't show any effort from you. You are just asking for code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a straight forward logic problem, and this is how you do it (<sup>*I'm sure there is a quicker alternative, but this does exactly what you need*</sup>):

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    list($item, $number) = explode(' ', $key);
    $new[$number][$item] = $val;
}
```

<sup>*We use [`list()`](http://php.net/list) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) in the above example to get the desired variables. Namely the number "one" or "two" and the item name, essentially "name" and "desc".*</sup>

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#DZCn65YPn)

---

#### EDIT

As Lajos stated, if the `$new[$number]` isn't set, this version will sort that out and create the required array:

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    list($item, $number) = explode(' ', $key);
    // if the array isn't set
    if(!isset($new[$number])) $new[$number] = array();
    $new[$number][$item] = $val;
}
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#hN68ae3G7)

Comment: What happens if $new[$number] is not set?

Comment: thank you! I hadn't actually tried anything yet I was wondering if there was a elegant way to do this prior to trying my own botched way. but looking at the answers I think that what i had in mind works perfectly ! thank you

Comment: thank you! so which one top accept???

Comment: @vimes1984 whichever answer suits your needs best!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
$target = array();
foreach ($elements as $k => $v) {
    $keys = explode(" ", $k);
    if (!isset($target[$keys[1]])) {
        $target[$keys[1]] = array();
    }
    $target[$keys[1]][$keys[0]] = $v;
}
```

Comment: `if (!isset($target[$keys[1]])) {
        $target[$keys[1]] = array();
    }` is not necessary at all.  Parent elements do not need to be declared in PHP before pushing a child element -- when using square brace syntax.